# Need to calculate cell date but only if the date is greater or equal to specific date

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, sharepoint

I am trying to create a date stamp for when a column `[Task Status]` is changed to complete. The following code successfully creates the date stamp when the "status" cell is changed to complete.

```
=IF([Task Status])= "Complete",TEXT(NOW(),"mm/dd/yyyy"))
```

The problem is that for all of the `[Task Status]` column cells are complete are going to show the date that the formula was implemented. I am looking for a solution that will create a date stamp for all days going forward and leave past dates blank.

I have tried this, but it is not working:

```
=IF(NOW()<="7/31/2020","",IF([Task Status]="Complete",TEXT(NOW(),"mm/dd/yyyy")))
```

Comment: If you use `NOW()` in your formula, the date completed will always show today's date. So if you change something to "Complete" tomorrow then tomorrow it will say 8/1/2020, but the following day it will say 8/2/2020, because it will always be based on `NOW()`. It sounds like you actually want a time-stamp that stays fixed at the date it was changed to complete. Do you?

Comment: Correct. That is what I am trying to achieve. A fixed time stamp once data in another cell has been updated.

Comment: Are you open to using [VBA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications)?

Answer (score 0):

As `FlexYourData` points out, using `NOW()` will mean all those dates/times that it creates will change each time a change (almost any change) is made to you spreadsheet because `NOW()` will recalculate each time the spreadsheet recalculates. So every new day the date will be different, but all through the day the time will change also.

You need a different approach to get the result you almost certainly hope for.

That said, the specific problem you are having in your formula is easy to fix. Excel treats dates and times as numbers. Each new day is one integer higher than the previous day so today, 2020-08-02 is 44045 and tomorrow will be 44046. Time marches up also, but on the decimal side of the value. So this moment is 44045.33844 and this moment is 44045.33876 and so on through the day until reaching 44046 and continuing on.

You have used the expression `NOW()<="7/31/2020"` in which the date is a string value, not a number. Strings always have a numerical value of 0. So you are asking Excel to see if `NOW()` (which we know will be a number higher than 0) is <= 0. Naturally, it says it is not and acts upon the parameter for `FALSE` results to that test.

If you **"wrap" that date in the `DATEVALUE()` function**, your formula will work as expected:

```
=IF(NOW()<=DATEVALUE("7/31/2020"),"",IF([Task Status]="Complete",TEXT(NOW(),"mm/dd/yyyy")))
```

**and that's all it takes.**

Solving how `NOW()` is volatile and will change endlessly is quite another thing.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, what I am trying to achieve is a timestamp that is stored when the value in another cell is changed. So, it sounds like another approach is needed due to the volatility of the Now() function.